# Get JRE from maven

Tags: java, maven

Is it still possible to download JRE from maven as a zip file, so that one can include it in the packaged product? I found this code, which doesn't work anymore:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>unpack</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>unpack</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <artifactItems>
                <artifactItem>
                  <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                  <artifactId>jre</artifactId>
                  <version>1.8.141</version>
                  <type>zip</type>
                  <classifier>windows-i586</classifier>
                  <outputDirectory>${basedir}</outputDirectory>
                </artifactItem>
              </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

UPDATE: Looks like such thing could only work after uploading the zip file to the own maven repo...

Comment: http://www.mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle.java/jre

Answer (score 1):

Change the version `1.8.141` to `1.8.0_131`. The [latest](http://www.mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle.java/jre) maven has this one only:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle.java/jre -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.java</groupId>
    <artifactId>jre</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.0_131</version>
</dependency>
```

**EDIT :As per the comments from OP**

> This example here is for a dependency. What I need is a maven goal to
>   copy unzipped JRE to a folder. And actually I do need a specific JRE
>   version. So currently, the solution is to install the JRE zip file in
>   my maven repo and unpack it with maven goal.

Copying and unzipping the `jre` artifact to another location may be achieved by [Maven Dependency Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-artifacts.html)

```
<project>
  [...]
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.java</groupId>
        <artifactId>jre</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0_131</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>unpack</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>unpack</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <artifactItems>
                <artifactItem>
                  <groupId>com.oracle.java</groupId>
                  <artifactId>jre</artifactId>
                  <type>zip</type>
                  <outputDirectory>/path/to/alternateLocation</outputDirectory>
                </artifactItem>
              </artifactItems>
             </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

Comment: I know, so I guess that's the last version available ... it's obviously not well maintained

Comment: Changing version in your maven plugin worked for you?

Comment: This example here is for a dependency. What I need is a maven goal to copy unzipped JRE to a folder. And actually I do need a specific JRE version. So currently, the solution is to install the JRE zip file in my maven repo and unpack it with maven goal.

Comment: @user1414745 I have added maven goal to copy unzipped JRE to another location. For specific JRE version, agree! if it is not available at maven central, you need to upload it to your own repo to access through maven build.

Comment: @user1414745 If this answer helps, please do not forget to upvote/accept it.